# A specific question about sakurai modern quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, matrix-elements

[image]

In the kronocker deltas for spin, $\lambda_4$ and $\lambda_3$ places changes. How can the author change their places?

Also, I see both case can appear by calculation so there are two different possibilities. How doesn't that change the physics.

Answer (score 0):

If my notes are correct, there is a typo with equation 7.147.

It should be $$\tag{7.147} ...=\frac{e^2}{V^2}\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_3}\delta_{\lambda2\lambda4}...$$ instead of $$\frac{e^2}{V^2}\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_4}\delta_{\lambda_2\lambda_3}...$$

This typo occured twice in 7.147.